# Nunjucks Set a Variable with a {% set %} {% endset %} an inline if else

Tags: nunjucks

I'm having some issues with a nunjucks code that a peer says has a valid syntax:

```
{% set variable%} {{ a if a > 0 else 1 }} {% endset %}
```

I know that they included inline if else but I can't find an example that combines it with a set.
Thanks in advance, hope you have a happy day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct

```
{% set myvar %} 
   {{ a if a > 0 else 1 }} 
{% endset %}
{{ myvar }}
```

For Node.js

```
const nunjucks  = require('nunjucks')
const env = nunjucks.configure()

const html = env.renderString(`
{% set myvar %} 
   {{ a if a > 0 else 1 }} 
{% endset %}
{{ myvar }}`, 
{ a: -10 });

console.log(html)
```